# Clarification of Theorem 24.1 from Munkres' Topology

Tags: general-topology

This is a theorem from Munkres' Topology.

[image]

Could someone please explain why $c=b$ implies $d$ is an upper bound for $A_0$?

Comment: Then $(d,b] \subset B_0$, whence $A_0 \subset [a,d]$.

Comment: $B_0$ is disjoint from $A$ and thus is also disjoint from $A_0$.  Since $(d,b] \subset B_0$, then d is an upper bound of $A_0$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you.

Comment: @gd1035 Thank you.